# Vuejs : How to Attach props conditionally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component A which is being imported in another component B. Component A opens in a modal when a button is clicked in component B. Component A is called blogPost. There are 2 use case .

1 One in which we need to pass 2 props when button is clicked.

```
<blogPost :token_id="tokenId" :token_url="tokenUrl"></blogPost>
```

2 One which does not need props when button is clicked

```
<blogPost></blogPost>
```

Is there any way we can attach props conditionally . I want to attach props based on a condition inDashboard. If inDashboard is true, I want case 1. If inDashboard is false, I want case 2. Is there a way to achieve this in a single line. Now I have 2 lines for them seperately in a seperate modal.

Comment: Please share code of model and also blogPost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

```
<blogPost :token_id="inDashboard?tokenId:null" :token_url="inDashboard?tokenUrl:null"></blogPost>
```

and then check it in blogPost either token_id and token_url have values or not

Answer (score 2):

`v-bind` could come in handy.

```html
<blogPost v-bind="inDashboard && postProps"></blogPost>
```

```js
{
  data: () => ({
    postProps: {
      token_id: 123,
      token_url: 'https://some.url'
    }
  })
}
```

What that does is, if the condition fails, it's not gonna evaluate the second expression, which basically binds it to `false` and will have no effect or be ignored (`v-bind` takes care of this internally); otherwise, it's going to assign the values (props) in one go.